# Wordpress Tag Cloud as link abuse

Tags: seo, tags

Do Wordpress Tag cloud considered as link farm or duplicate content? How about categories?

After many recent algo updates by Google, did Google created an algo not to penalize sites CMS site like Wordpress with tags and categories?

I am using Yoast's **NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW**, does it help?

I have approximately 50+ of tags and currently displayed on each of my blog posts, including the blog homepage.

I am looking for the modern answer for this question and modern resources from answers.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't so much "link abuse" problem as a thin content problem and a PageRank dilution problem.

Tag and category pages...

- often don't have much content, especially when a tag is only used on one or two posts.
- are full of duplicate content.   Everything that is on a tag page is also found on the post pages.
- are usually poor landing pages.  There is no way to "stick" the best posts to the top of a tag page.  Content is always ordered by recency.  Anybody visiting a tag page as their first experience on your site may feel the content is "random".  A tag page isn't going to be anybody's choice for a "canonical" resource about a topic.
- don't pass PageRank around the site well.   A better choice is linking directly to "related posts" on the post page.  Some related posts algorithms to use the tags for this purpose.

My recommendations for tag and category pages are:

- Use `noindex,follow` in the robots meta tag.  Search engines don't like to index them, but having them follow the links is fine.
- Don't put tag clouds or category lists on every page on your site.   They can be useful for users on the homepage, but they clutter up the site when used everywhere.
- Use a related posts plugin for the post pages